# Visual Studio Code: Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml, requires an update

Tags: java, maven, configuration, pom.xml, project

Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

[{
"resource": "/C:/Automation/automation-selenium/Reports-CDC/pom.xml",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#3",
"code": "0",
"severity": 4,
"message": "Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml, requires an update.",
"source": "Java",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 1
}]

[Problems with pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8sRs.png)

Java 11 is installed, although when I go to **Configure Java Runtime**, I only see the pencils for **Java Version**. If I click on one of those pencils, then it just takes me back to the pom.xml file. It's a bit of a vicious cycle that I don't know how to get out of. As a result, when I attempt to run my Selenide tests, I get **No tests found in this file.**

[Configure Runtime for Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZdP.png)

I have tried rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling both VSCode and Java 11 JDK, but none of it helps. The **import** items at the top of my Java classes used to be green, but now they are in white.

I have testing extensions installed, including Test Runner for Java. I also have Git & GitHub Extension Pack and so forth.

I have tried the command **mvn clean install -U **

I have updated my **defaultSettings.json** file to match that of my colleague who does not seem to be experiencing any of these problems.

When I click on the **Testing** beaker, I see "No tests have been found in this workspace yet." When I click **Install Additional Test Extensions**, it shows **Test Runner for Java** already installed.

Comment: I was able to remove those problems simply by going into the pom.xml and clicking "Reload Projects." However, I am not out of the woods yet because the imports are still white in my Java classes, and I still can't use the Test Runner beaker.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tried all the things you did with no success.

Finally, I found this [vscode Java Troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting). Following the tips there, I opened the Java Language Server workspace log and reloaded vscode.  The log showed an error that a maven dependency plugin could not be resolved.

I commented out the plugin reference in the POM and then the Java environment loaded correctly.

The frustrating part is that I could run mvn install on this project with no errors from the command line.  I went back to the POM and re-added the plugin the problem in vscode did not reoccur.